# Material-UI unchanged colors when switching back and forth between themes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm changing the theme in my application via a state variable and the `MuiThemeProvider`
When switching the active theme the colors on all components update correctly, but only once. If I switch back to a theme that's already been used the colors do not update.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-mcnulty-0tzm2?file=/src/App.js

You can see that on the codesandbox, switching back and forth causes the last theme to "stick" if the theme you're changing to has already been used.

I can "fix" this issue by using `theme.palette.primary.main` on `makeStyles()` when styling my components but that kinda defeats the purpose of the `color` properties for the components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material-UI does not yet fully support `StrictMode` (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20708). If you remove the `<React.StrictMode>` tags in index.js it works fine.

Here's a working version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strictmode-theme-switching-issues-7prfe.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Strict Mode Theme with the following import.

```
import { unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

But as you can see it says unstable and I don't know the disadvantages of creating a theme that way, for the moment it's working on my personal projects while having a global Strict Mode.

[Documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)