# Material-ui creates extra <style data-jss="" data-meta="..."> when using reducer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I noticed that every time I click on a button that invokes my useReducer, a copy of each `<style data-jss="" data-meta="...">`  See screenshot, each purple tag is created when I clicked on a button. Is that normal?
If not, how do I prevent it from happening?
full code I'm working on is at https://github.com/LazaroFilm/lazaro_creations_shop
Not sure what code snippet would be relevant here...[image]

Comment: This is due to using `StrictMode` in `index.js`. v4 of Material-UI does not fully support strict mode and it does not correctly clean up styles when strict mode is used. Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935784/material-ui-unchanged-colors-when-switching-back-and-forth-between-themes/62937005#62937005. v5 (still months away from stable release) will fully support strict mode.

Comment: @victor-lazaro were you able to find the fix?

Comment: The answer is above your comment. It has to do with Strict mode.